# Python graph plot issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, time-series

I am trying to plot a time-series data, but I'm facing some issue while plotting them like when I'm using function

```
pyplot.plot(ts)
```

graph is like

[image: first plot using function]

But when I'm using following function of python on same data then graph is like this

```
ts.plot()
```

[image: second graph]

I'm totally confused because of this. Any idea about this error?

Comment: Probably the dates are not ordered

Comment: Can you clarify your answer bit elaborately please. How I can handle this issue.

Comment: Dates are in well order. I have checked it

Comment: it seems that in the beginning there is all year 2017, then 2016, 2015 and so on. To plot properly, it should start from 2003, then 2004 and year 2017 as last. Is it so?

Comment: Yes, it is starting from 2017 then going towards 2003

Comment: You should order the df. See the answer if it solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the df, I can only make a guess. You should order the column which contains the dates. Try to apply this to the column of `x-axis` where the dates are:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='your_column') #'your_column' is the columns with dates
```